# Face Frame Cabinet Hinges won't close

Tags: doors, kitchens, cabinets, hinges, frame

I have some large cabinet doors (3 hinges on each door) which I recently installed new soft-close hinges however the left side the bottom of the door won't close and on the right side the top of the door won't close.  This causes the cabinet doors to both angle and not be completely flat and aligned with each other.

Soft Close hinges from Home Depot:
https://www.homedepot.com/p/Everbilt-35-mm-105-Degree-1-1-4-in-Overlay-Soft-Close-Cabinet-Hinge-5-Pairs-H1531SE-NP-U1/302854550

Is there anything I can do to get the doors to close?  Do I need to bend the hinges or anything?

**Additional Information**

Adjusted the left / right, up / down, and forward / backward positions, but the bottom right portion of the left cabinet is still not closing and sticks out a bit and the right cabinet door on the top left isn't closing.  In terms of left / right and up / down those are adjusted "correctly".  In terms of forward and backward, there seems to be some deviations that can't be corrected with the forward / backward adjustments or the deviation is too much for the max / min adjustment limits.

Comment: Have you tried all the adjustments on the hinges?  Can the doors be switched?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Those hinges are adjustable for just this purpose; see if there's documentation. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Updated the main post for details on using the micro adjustments on the hinge.  It doesn't have enough adjustment leeway to compensate for the odd angles it is creating for the forward and backward positions.

Comment: Are the two doors identical?  Can they be swapped?  There might be some slight warpage  that could be corrected.